# insert custom object's record into standard object

Tags: apex, trigger

I am trying to write a trigger which will be triggered when an opportunity update event occurs. for that I have written an update event as below.

```
Opportunity o = [select Discount_Percent__c from Opportunity where Discount_Percent__c=11];
o.Discount_Percent__c=1;
update o;
```

And I have one custom object called "MyTest" with two field (Name & Approval Status). So I created a trigger as below.

```
trigger InsertNewRecordTOForTriggerPractice on Opportunity (after update) {    
    for(Opportunity objectOfOpp : trigger.new) {
        if(objectOfOpp.Id=='0067F000002tbN3') {
            MyTest__c mytest = new MyTest__c();
            mytest.Name='Mytestone';
            mytest.Approval_Status__c='Not Approved';
            insert mytest;
        } 
    }  
}
```

So for example, If i am trying to update an opportunity having record id 0067F000002tbN3, I am trying created new record for object "MyTest" inside Opportunity object with id=0067F000002tbN3.

The above trigger written is working fine, it is creating a MyTest record separately but not inside the Opportunity object. **(I mean I want to insert new record into the that opportunity on which update event occurs).**

Can anyone help me to solve my problem.

Comment: What do you mean by "inside the opportunity object"? Does you `MyTest__c` object have a look up field related to an `Opportunity` object? Does your `Opportunity` object has a lookup field related to your `MyTest__c` object?

Comment: @MartinLezer sorry for not mentioning it mistakenly.. But yes,MyTest_c object have a look up field related to an opportunity object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After referring some documents.I myself found a solution for this problem.

```
trigger InsertNewMyTestInsideOpp on Opportunity (after update) {  
    for(Opportunity objectOfOpp : trigger.new) {
            MyTest__c mytest = new MyTest__c();
            mytest.Name='Mytestseven';
            mytest.Opportunity__c=objectOfOpp.Id; // This is for lookup field 
            mytest.Approval_Status__c='Not Approved';
            insert mytest;
    }  
}
```

I think we dont need to check the Opportunity which is being updated/inserted using 'if' condition. Because 'trigger.new' stores the records which are currently in context of trigger, either being inserted or updated.

This solves my problem. Thank You !!!